# Реализовать сложение двумерных массивов разной длины

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Имеется код, позволяющий сложить два массива одинакового размера, можно ли его как-то отредактировать так, чтобы была возможность сложить два массива разных размеров?

```
int m, n, m1, n1, f, g;
    int ** arr;
    int ** arr2;
    int ** arrsum;
     void sum()
        {
            f = m;
            g = n;

                arrsum = new int *[f];
                for (int i = 0; i < f; i++)
                {
                    arrsum[i] = new int[g];
                    for (int j = 0; j < g; j++)
                        cout << setfill(' ') << setw(2) << (arrsum[i][j] = arr[i][j] + arr2[i][j]) << " ";
                    cout << "\n";
                }
        }
```

Comment: Конечно, можно - только сначала надо определить логику для такого сложения.

Comment: Как только вы определите, что такое сумма матриц разных размеров - так сразу...

Comment: Напрашивается несколько вопросов 1. Каких размеров вы хотели бы видеть `arrsum`? Наименьшего из возможных (то есть берем кол-во столбцов из наименьшего массива и аналогично со строками) или наибольшего из возможных (то есть кол-во столбцов и строк берем из наибольших массивов)? Если наименьшего, то итерируйтесь по `min(n, n1)`,  `min(m, m1)` и создавайте `arrsum` таких размеров. Если наибольшего, то тогда вопрос 2. Что должно происходить, если в одном из исходных массивов на позиции `[i][j]` есть элемент, а в другом нет? Исходя из своих желаний сделайте соответствующую проверку и все остальное